# Close multiple tabs opened with Javascript after they've loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a java-script function being used to open multiple different tabs at once as shown below.

How do I go about getting the tabs to close automatically after they've loaded?

This is how I'm currently loading them in the function:

```
                var URL1 = 'some link here';
                var URL2 = 'some link here';
                var URL3 = 'some link here';
                var URL4 = 'some link here';
                var URL5 = 'some link here';
                var URL6 = 'some link here';
                var URL7 = 'some link here';
                var URL8 = 'some link here';
                var URL9 = 'some link here';
                var URL10 = 'some link here';
                var URL11 = 'some link here';
                var URL12 = 'some link here';
                var URL13 = 'some link here';
                var URL14 = 'some link here';


                var URL_FINAL1 = encodeURI(URL1);
                var URL_FINAL2 = encodeURI(URL2);
                var URL_FINAL3 = encodeURI(URL3);
                var URL_FINAL4 = encodeURI(URL4);
                var URL_FINAL5 = encodeURI(URL5);
                var URL_FINAL6 = encodeURI(URL6);
                var URL_FINAL7 = encodeURI(URL7);
                var URL_FINAL8 = encodeURI(URL8);
                var URL_FINAL9 = encodeURI(URL9);
                var URL_FINAL10 = encodeURI(URL10);
                var URL_FINAL11 = encodeURI(URL11);
                var URL_FINAL12 = encodeURI(URL12);
                var URL_FINAL13 = encodeURI(URL13);



                window.open(URL_FINAL1, '_blank');
                window.open(URL_FINAL2, '_blank');
                window.open(URL_FINAL3, '_blank');
                window.open(URL_FINAL4, '_blank');
                window.open(URL_FINAL5, '_blank');
                window.open(URL_FINAL6, '_blank');
                window.open(URL_FINAL7, '_blank');
                window.open(URL_FINAL8, '_blank');
                window.open(URL_FINAL9, '_blank');
                window.open(URL_FINAL10, '_blank');
                window.open(URL_FINAL11, '_blank');
                window.open(URL_FINAL12, '_blank');
                window.open(URL_FINAL13, '_blank');


            });
    }
```

The above then opens 13 new tabs which just on load submits some internal data so the user doesn't actually have to do anything on the 13 pages except let it fully load.

Ideally I'd like to have the tabs closed automatically instead of having the user "x" on 13 tabs

Comment: I think you'll find that closing the tabs isn't as simple as you think - it's interacting with the program on the sers computer so you'll struggle finding a way to do this.

Comment: Are newly opened windows same-origin?

Comment: @StanislavKvitash yes they are.

Comment: @Toblerone so try the approach from my answer and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If urls have the same host and the same protocol then using [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event listener and [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) should do the trick:

```
var onLoadFn = function() { this.close(); };
window.open(URL_FINAL1, '_blank').addEventListener('load', onLoadFn);
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly the tabs stayed opened.

Comment: Still no luck sadly.

Comment: @Toblerone strange thing, this worked for me. How the submission works when the window is loaded? Can you please provide some sample?

Comment: (Sadly i'm unable to share screenshots etc due to this being used for something internal@ work) - Generally what happens on button click is that 13 new tabs are opened to a java-script development environment where some action automatically happens just by loading the page - the links are all same host but points to different sections like url 1 = (https://xxxx/1) url 2 = (https://xxxx/2) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

try running `window.close();` command in each tab which are opened through `window.open();` command.